# F12 brings me to Metadata only

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

Using Visual Studio 2017 CE. 15.7.4. Every time I press F12 on a class or a method it will only takes me to the Metadata and not the actual implementation.

I add references by project not Assembly. Removing the reference and re ad it 
does not help.

This only happens for this solution with .NET Core 2.1 and .NET standard 2.0. In another solution. In 2 other projects using .NET 4.6 it works fine.

So I suspect it could be the .NET CORE project/solution files?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Nope, still annoying as ..

Comment: For no apparent reason, a week ago my solution started having this issue. I upgraded VS to the latest version (as of right now, v15.8.1) and the issue went away.